# How can I capture raw messages that are coming out to OpenAI API?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I'm using LangChain to build prompts that are later sent to the OpenAI API. I've built an agent, but it's behaving a bit differently than I expected. It looks like it's missing some of my instructions that I included in the prompt. Specifically: it seems to not remember past messages. I'm looking for a way to debug it.

Here's more or less how I'm building the agent. I'm not including everything; it's just for general information on what I'm using.

```py
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)
agent_chain = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True, memory=memory)
agent_chain.run(input="hi, I am Bob")
```

As far as I know, LangChain itself adds some parts of prompts. For example, this particular agent I use add some information about how the answer should be structured. But this is not transparent to the end user, the final prompt is being constructed inside the library. Even in verbose mode I can't see every part of the sent prompt.

Is there any way I could retrieve complete, raw messages sent to the OpenAI API and responses from it?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the problem using the tool *[LangChain Visualizer](https://github.com/amosjyng/langchain-visualizer)*.

It shows all the inputs and outputs sent to the API in the form of an execution tree like this:

[image]

It is not the ideal solution, but it does its job.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to events using a callback and store them in PlantUML format Activity and Sequence Diagram. You can easily subscribe to events and keep them in a form that is easy to visualize and analyze.

https://github.com/coolbeevip/langchain_plantuml
[image]